# (local variable) int PlaceNumberValue Error: Cannot Implicity convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#

Buenas noches les dejo este pequeño error no puedo convertir la variable 'PlaceNumberValue' de string a entero aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TrackerLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represent what the prize if for the given place.
    /// </summary>
    public class PrizeModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The unique identifier for the prize
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The numeric identifier for the place(for the second place, etc.)
        /// </summary>
        public int PlaceNumber { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The friendly name for the place (second place, first runner up, etc.)
        /// </summary>

        public string PlaceName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The find amount this place earns or zero if it is not used.
        /// </summary>

        public decimal PrizeAmount { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The number that represent the percentage of theoverall take or
        /// zero if it is not used. The percentage if a fraction of 1 (so O.S for
        /// 50%)
        /// </summary>

        public double PrizePercentage { get; set; }

        public PrizeModel()
        {

        }

        public PrizeModel(string placeName, string placeNumber, string placeAmount, string placePercentage)
        {
            PlaceName = PlaceName;
            int placeNumberValue = 0;
            int.TryParse(placeNumber, out placeNumberValue);
            placeNumber = placeNumberValue; //AQUI ESTA EL ERROR

            decimal prizeAmountValue = 0;
            decimal.TryParse(prizeAmount, out prizeAmountValue);
            PrizeAmount = prizeAmountValue;
        }


        public string prizeAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Eso es por que estas igualando dos tipos de dato distintos. Te explico un poco de como funciona esto...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variable tipo int
            int placeNumberValue = 0;
            //Varible tipo string
            string placeNumber= "30";

            // En caso de que el valor string no sea numero, por ejemplo "Vdfd5" el valor sera 0, ya que es un try catch
            //interno
            int.TryParse(placeNumber, out placeNumberValue);

            //Estas igulando un tipo string a int
            //Para hacer una igualación, tienen que ser del mismo tipo
            //Es decir  int a, b;  a=b;   string c,d; c=d;           
            //Place number es string, y place number value es int

            // Place number es string, para que la igualdad sea del mismo tipo convertimos ese int a string
            placeNumber = placeNumberValue.ToString(); //AQUI ESTA EL ERROR

            //Si necesitas trabajar con los enteros
            int placeNumberInt = int.Parse(placeNumber);


            //Recuerda que Parse es para convertir un string de un valor que tiene caracteres numericos como "4564"
            //El Try parse es para evitar errores si te el string es "AX78", y el out es para reasignarle un valor válido que predeterminas tú (En tu caso predeterminaste 0)


            Console.Write(placeNumberInt+5);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Espero te haber sido de ayuda.
Saludos!!!**

Comment: Ya no me da error muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @Cpp si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, considera votarla positivamente y marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo.